# Problem solved by customer support with a premade executable

Tags: discussion

I recently asked [Open a cash drawer using a RJ11 DIO 12/24V port in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/990176/open-a-cash-drawer-using-a-rj11-dio-12-24v-port-in-windows-7), and while looking for an answer I contacted the customer support of **Shuttle**.

They replied with a message which was a bit like this:

> Please find attached a software tool for your request, you can use it by doing [...].

So basically, this solved my problem, but I cannot give the software to anyone since it is not mine, so basically the only answer I could write would be like:

> For anyone having the same issue, you should contact Shuttle support [...].

...which I don't know if it is acceptable. What should I do with that question?

Comment: Have you tried contacting their support and asking if the tool is publicly available? Say you wanted to write a blog about the problem and would like to mention the tool as a fix...

Comment: @Mokubai I just did, they said no, so I will follow Oliver's advice, thanks for your help!

Comment: No worries. As Oliver mentioned that is a perfectly valid answer, it just seemed worth a try to see if the tool could be released so it would benefit more people. Glad you got a fix for your problem.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Explaining that you contacted support and received a tool from them, which solves the issue, is a perfectly acceptable answer to the question.

Anyone with the same problem will be happy to read that.

Comment: Especially if you can then explain how you used it and what it did (as that may be more helpful than support's explanation).